# qt- setting validator for input from tableview

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt-creator

i have created a QTableView which gets data from QSqlTableModel but i want to set validation so that value changed from tableview is same with my data format.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom delegate for the items in your view and override `setModelData` method in it to intercept the attempt to insert the improperly formatted data:

```
class MyDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyDelegate(QObject * parent = 0);

    virtual void setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model,
           const QModelIndex & index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

Q_SIGNALS:
    void improperlyFormattedDataDetected(int row, int column, QString data);

private:
    bool checkDataFormat(const QString & data) const;
};

MyDelegate::MyDelegate(QObject * parent) :
    QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{}

void MyDelegate::setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    // Assuming the model stores strings so the editor is QLineEdit
    QLineEdit * lineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    if (!lineEdit) {
        // Whoops, looks like the assumption is wrong, fallback to the default implementation
        QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor, model, index);
        return;
    }

    QString data = lineEdit->text();
    if (checkDataFormat(data)) {
        // The data is formatted properly, letting the default implementation from the base class set this to the model
        QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor, model, index);
        return;
    }

    // If we got here, the data format is wrong. We should refuse to put the data into the model
    // and probably signal about this attempt to the outside world so that the view can connect to this signal,
    // receive it and do something about it - show a warning tooltip or something.
    emit improperlyFormattedDataDetected(index.row(), index.column(), data);
}
```

Once the custom delegate is implemented, you need to set it to your view:

```
view->setItemDelegate(new MyDelegate(view));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the data format you refer to is a type of validation. If so,
another way to do this would be add an actual custom `MyValidator -> QValidator` (`->` implies derived from). @Dmitry's code would be the same, except you have to instantiate a `MyValidator` object in your delegate as a member and then set the validator on the line editor as:

```
myValidator = new MyValidator; // some args if you need ...
lineEdit->setValidator (&myValidator);
```

In the `MyValidator` class you should implement the pure `virtual QValidator::State validate(QString& input, int& pos) const` method of the `QValidator` class. You can put all your formatting and validation rules in there.

The user won't be able to get out of the line editor without providing the data in the right format as per your custom rules. No need to invoke any other message box.

I had an almost exact same requirement, and this solution worked great for me!

Comment: yeah i know about line edit but how to implement it in table view

Comment: Use @Dmitry's answer to create a custom delegate. In addition you should override `createEditor` method and then as indicated in my answer attach a custom `QValidator` to the created editor, while providing `validate()` method.